# Iterating over elements, finding minima per each element

Tags: python, numpy

First time posting, so I apologize for any confusion.

I have two numpy arrays which are time stamps for a signal.

chan1,chan2 looks like:

```
911.05, 7.7
1055.6, 455.0
1513.4, 1368.15
4604.6, 3004.4
4970.35, 3344.25
13998.25, 4029.9
15008.7, 6310.15
15757.35, 7309.75
16244.2, 8696.1
16554.65, 9940.0
...,   ...
```

and so on, (up to 65000 elements per chan. pre file)
Edit : The lists are already sorted but the issue is that they are not always equal in spacing. There are gaps that could show up, which would misalign them, so chan1[3] could be closer to chan2[23] instead of, if the spacing was qual chan2[2 or 3 or 4] : End edit

For each elements in chan1, I am interested in finding the closest neighbor in chan2, which is done with:

```
$ np.min(np.abs(chan2-chan1[i]))
```

and to keep track of positive or neg. difference:

```
$ index=np.where( np.abs( chan2-chan1[i]) == res[i])[0][0]
$ if chan2[index]-chan1[i] <0.0 : res[i]=res[i]*(-1.0)
```

Lastly, I create a histogram of all the differences, in a range I am interested in.

My concern is that I do this in the for loop. I usually try to avoid for loops when I can by utilizing the numpy arrays, as each operation can be performed on the entire array. However, in this case I am unable to find a solution or a build in function (which I understand run significantly faster than anything I can make). 
The routine takes about 0.03 seconds per file. There are a few more things happening outside of the function but not a significant number, mostly plotting after everything is done, and a loop to read in files.

I was wondering if anyone has seen a similar problem, or is familiar enough with the python libraries to suggest a solution (maybe a build in function?) to obtain the data I am interested in? I have to go over hundred of thousands of files, and currently my data analysis is about 10 slower than data acquisition. We are also in the middle of upgrading our instruments to where we will be able to obtain data 10-100 times faster, and so the analysis speed is going to become an serious issue.

I would prefer not to use a cluster to brute force the problem, and not too familiar with parallel processing, although I would not mind dabbling in it. It would take me a while to write it in C, and I am not sure if I would be able to make it faster.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
 def gen_hist(chan1,chan2):
     res=np.arange(1,len(chan1)+1,1)*0.0
     for i in range(len(chan1)):
         res[i]=np.min(np.abs(chan2-chan1[i]))
         index=np.where( np.abs( chan2-chan1[i]) == res[i])[0][0]
         if chan2[index]-chan1[i] <0.0 : res[i]=res[i]*(-1.0)
     return np.histogram(res,bins=np.arange(time_range[0]-interval,\
                                            time_range[-1]+interval,\
                                            interval))[0]
```

After all the files are cycled through I obtain a plot of the data:
[Example of the histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXQ9B.png)

Comment: I see code but no question

Comment: First time asking a question. I need to find a faster way to do this. Was wondering if there is a build in function to achieve this task?
I have two numpy arrays, with time stamps. I need to get difference between the closes element by value in the other channel. Looking at the histogram after.
This takes about 0.03 seconds to run on my machine per file. I have 100000+ files. (messed up posting the question)

Comment: You can and should edit your question. Using the `edit` button underneath the question text. Instead of putting your question in a comment.

Comment: Your question is very not clear - please edit it and add the question plus example of input and output.

Comment: What about sorting the two lists and then find the differences by walking on the sorted list?

Comment: This is a good suggestion @Tom Ron. The lists are already sorted but the issue is that they are not always equal in spacing. There are gaps that could show up, which would misalign them. (Edited the body of the question)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but I'm assuming that, given two sorted arrays, you're trying to return an array containing the differences between each element of the first array and the closest value in the second array.

Your algorithm will have a worst case of `O(n^2)` (`np.where()` and [`np.min()`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/calculation.c#L289) are `O(n)`).  I would tackle this by using two iterators instead of one.  You store the previous (`r_p`) and current (`r_c`) value of the right array and the current (`l_c`) value of the left array.  For each value of the left array, increment the right array until `r_c > l_c`.  Then append `min(abs(r_p - l_c), abs(r_c - l_c))` to your result.

In code:

```
l = [ ... ]
r = [ ... ]
i = 0
j = 0
result = []
r_p = r_c = r[0]
while i < len(l):
    l_c = l[i]
    while r_c < l and j < len(r):
        j += 1
        r_c = r[j]
        r_p = r[j-1]
    result.append(min(abs(r_c - l_c), abs(r_p - l_c)))
    i += 1
```

This runs in `O(n)`.  If you need additional speed out of it, try [writing it in C](https://docs.python.org/3.3/extending/extending.html) or running it in [Cython](http://cython.org/).